# Pip requirements file execution order?

Tags: python, pip

Does a pip requirements file execute commands **sequentially**? I feel like this is sensible, but I cannot find any documented confirmation (perhaps because it is obvious...)

I have several packages which can be installed from the default package index, and several more which are stored in a local area. The local packages are installed using `--find-links``.

If my requirements file was;

```
packageA==0.1
packageB==0.2

--find-links path/to/local/repository
localA==1.0
localB==2.0
```

Would the `path/to/local/repository` only be searched for `localA` and `localB` or is that 'flag' applied before any of the packages are installed?

Further, if I did something like;

```
packageA==0.1
packageB==0.2

--no-index
--find-links path/to/local/repository
localA==1.0
localB==2.0
```

Is the `--no-index` flag only applied for packages AFTER it is defined, or to all in the file?

Comment: Reading the requirements file is essentially the same as passing the options from command line directly, so it's equivalent to calling `pip install packageA==0.1 packageB==0.2 --no-index --find-links path/to/local/repository localA==1.0 localB==2.0`. There are no multiple commands executed, the order doesn't matter and the flags are applied to the whole command, not separate arguments.

Comment: Great. Many thanks for the clarification